# Getting NestedServletException in Junits of SpringBoot project

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mongodb

I have a SpringBoot project with Mongo DB connection, application is working fine, but Junits are failing with below exception when `mongoTemplate.find(query, SchedulerEntity.class)` is called in Impl class.

Am I missing anything here?

I have used MockMvc to mock the APIs and get the data from MongoDB.

**Code where exception is thrown:**

```
@Override
    public List<SchedulerEntity> findByClientId(String clientId) {
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(where(CLIENT_NAME).is(clientId));
        return mongoTemplate.find(query, SchedulerEntity.class);
    }
```

**JUnit code:**

```
   @Test
    public void test_GetClientSchedules() throws Exception {
        SchedulerDTO schedulerDTO = createSchedulerDTO();
        SchedulerEntity schedularDomain = schedulerConverter.createSchedularDomain(schedulerDTO);

        String url = "/alerting/clients/" + schedulerDTO.getClientName() + "/schedules";
        logger.info("Url ::: " + url);
        mockMvc.perform(get(url)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk());

    }
```

**Error Stack Trace:**

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mongodb.DBCollection.find(Lcom/mongodb/DBObject;Lcom/mongodb/DBObject;IIIILcom/mongodb/ReadPreference;Lcom/mongodb/DBDecoder;)Lcom/mongodb/QueryResultIterator;
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1302)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:977)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:65)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:155)
    at com.adp.smartconnect.clientprofile.controller.SchedularControllerTest.test_GetClientSchedules(SchedularControllerTest.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mongodb.DBCollection.find(Lcom/mongodb/DBObject;Lcom/mongodb/DBObject;IIIILcom/mongodb/ReadPreference;Lcom/mongodb/DBDecoder;)Lcom/mongodb/QueryResultIterator;
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor._check(DBCursor.java:498)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor._hasNext(DBCursor.java:621)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:657)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1898)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1723)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1706)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:602)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:593)
    at com.adp.smartconnect.clientprofile.repository.SchedulerEntityRepositoryImpl.findByClientId(SchedulerEntityRepositoryImpl.java:39)
    at com.adp.smartconnect.clientprofile.service.SchedulerService.getClientSchedules(SchedulerService.java:45)
    at com.adp.smartconnect.clientprofile.controller.SchedularController.getClientSchedules(SchedularController.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    ... 41 more
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.adp.smartconnect</groupId>
  <artifactId>clientconfig-api</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.adp.smartconnect</groupId>
    <artifactId>clientconfig-services-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <commons.io.version>2.4</commons.io.version>
    <commons.lang3.version>3.1</commons.lang3.version>
    <fongo.version>1.3.1</fongo.version>
    <lombok.version>1.16.6</lombok.version>
    <jsondoc.version>1.2.10</jsondoc.version>
    <maven.plugin.buildnumber>1.4</maven.plugin.buildnumber>
    <mockito.version>1.9.5</mockito.version>
    <nosqlunit.mongodb.version>0.7.8</nosqlunit.mongodb.version>
    <orika.version>1.4.6</orika.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.6.4</slf4j.version>
    <tomcat.version>8.0.3</tomcat.version>
    <build.timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</build.timestamp>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ</maven.build.timestamp.format>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.fakemongo</groupId>
      <artifactId>fongo</artifactId>
      <version>${fongo.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>${commons.lang3.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.adp.smartconnect</groupId>
      <artifactId>clientconfig-payload</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
      <version>${mockito.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ma.glasnost.orika</groupId>
      <artifactId>orika-core</artifactId>
      <version>${orika.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>${commons.io.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jsondoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsondoc-ui-webjar</artifactId>
      <version>${jsondoc.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.lordofthejars</groupId>
      <artifactId>nosqlunit-mongodb</artifactId>
      <version>${nosqlunit.mongodb.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
          <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>fongo</artifactId>
          <groupId>com.foursquare</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-beanutils-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <useDefaultDelimiters>true</useDefaultDelimiters>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.plugin.buildnumber}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>create</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <shortRevisionLength>11</shortRevisionLength>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.5.201505241946</version>
        <executions>
          <!--                        Prepares the property pointing to the JaCoCo runtime agent which                        is passed as VM argument when Maven the Surefire plugin is executed.                    -->
          <execution>
            <id>pre-unit-test</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
              <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
              <!--                                Sets the name of the property containing the settings                                for JaCoCo runtime agent.                            -->
              <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <!--                        Ensures that the code coverage report for unit tests is created after                        unit tests have been run.                    -->
          <execution>
            <id>post-unit-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
              <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
              <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
              <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.15</version>
        <configuration>
          <argLine />
          <!-- Sets the VM argument line used when unit tests are run. -->
          <argLine>${surefireArgLine} -Dspring.profiles.active=default</argLine>
          <!-- Skips unit tests if the value of skip.unit.tests property is true -->
          <skipTests>${skip.unit.tests}</skipTests>
          <!-- Excludes integration tests when unit tests are run. -->
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/IT*.java</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you share your test class, too? And the part where the code fails.

Comment: share your method code where this error thrown

Comment: @Patrick  added code where exception is thrown

Comment: @sumitchoudhary added junit code

Comment: are you returning response object to get request. it seems that you returning **SchedulerEntity.class** object and expecting **response.ok**

Comment: @sumitchoudhary I don't think that is the root cause, exception is triggered in  mongoTemplate.find.

Comment: have you tried to call this method direct from main method..?

Comment: Add your dependencies (pom or gradle build file).

Comment: @M.Deinum please see pom file